# google sheets,yahoo finance,price and dividend data

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance

I created my own international portfolio tracker / dividend tracker through google sheets & yahoo finance.

The problem with international stocks is that you often cannot simply use the integrated data from google finance. KO (coca cola) is easy, CCC3.DE (also coca cola) cannot be found on google finance. suddenly some formulas stop working for some of the tickers.

For Example AD.AS does work but ccc3.de does not work.

For price is use; `A1 = "CCC3.DE" or "AD.AS"`

```
  =IFNA(VALUE(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" &A1, "//*[@class=""D(ib) Mend(20px)""]/span[1]")))
```

For dividend amount I use;

```
=split(IMPORTXML(concatenate("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",index(split((E9&F9&G9),":"),0,2)),$F$22),"()"))/K9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Yahoo changed some things in their website and it resulted to the import formula not to work anymore for some of the webpage in Yahoo Finance as well as for some tickers. This is the result of the IMPORTXML command for the CCC3.DE ticker.

[image]

For now, I suggest finding another website/data source that will give you the same information that you need for those unavailable/unscrapeable tickers. Another option would be to wait for yahoo to fix this issue.

Comment: Oef, hopefully this will be fixed soon, is there a chance that it will never work again? making this tracker took me ages.

Comment: I can't say for sure but one thing I am sure of is that you are not the only one using Yahoo Finance for fetching data so there will be a lot of complaints on their end. :)

Comment: If this answer helped you. Please do accept or/and upvote to help others in the community to see the most relevant answer to your concern. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers